# multiple .htaccess rewrite rules for custom PHP MVC framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, model-view-controller

I am trying to build a `custom PHP MVC framework`, I want to do the following using `.htaccess` rewrite

`localhost/mvc/page1` OR `localhost/mvc/page1/` 
To this
`localhost/mvc/index/view/page1`

**AND**

`localhost/mvc/blog` OR `localhost/mvc/blog/`
To this
`localhost/mvc/blog/index`

**AND**

`localhost/mvc/blog/blog1` OR `localhost/mvc/blog/blog1/`
To this
`localhost/mvc/blog/view/blog1`

here `index` and `blog` are controllers

Below is what I have tried so far

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=index/view/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This redirects `localhost/mvc/page1` To `localhost/mvc/index/view/page1`

So basically, I want to have different rewrite conditions for different controllers. So when I will add a new controller I will keep adding condition to htaccess file as well.

This is a code behind redirect (URL should not change),. and everything behind `localhost/mvc/` should be reflected in GET `$_GET['rt']` parameter

How to achieve this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mvc/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(blog)/?$ index.php?rt=$1/index [L,NC,QSA] 

RewriteRule ^(blog)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?rt=$1/view/$2 [L,NC,QSA] 

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?rt=index/view/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks so much.. that worked :).. so whenever I want to add a new controller, I have to add the redirect rule before that default index rule right??

Comment: Yes that's right, last rule is catch-all controller.

Comment: Just for curiosity .. How to redirect if I have something like `localhost/mvc/blog/blog1/edit` to `localhost/mvc/blog/view/blog1/edit`

Comment: Then change 2nd rule to `RewriteRule ^(blog)/(.+)/?$ index.php?rt=$1/view/$2 [L,NC,QSA]`